# Pen-drive got corrupted after making it bootable

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, formatting, iso-image

One of my friends windows got corrupted. So, I downloaded the PowerISO and Windows 7 iso. By using PowerISO I made it bootable with adding Windows 7 to it. And he successfully installed Windows but after that when i formatted pen-drive and tried to use it, The pen-drive was not showing in explorer. Help.

Comment: If you open Disk Management while the pen-drive is attached, do you see it there? Does it have a partition? Does it have a drive letter assigned? Do you have "hide empty drives" enabled in explorer, so its simply hidden?

Comment: @LPChip Nothing there but when i connect it with my phone It works and I can store files in it.

Comment: If you plug it into a different USB port, so it can reinstall itself?

Comment: Did the pen drive not perhaps drop? try another one and see if the problem persists?

Comment: LPChip I have already tried it; @MartinKronstrom Nope and It is working in mobile as it is a mobile+usb pendrive.